# Finding Ultimate Parent of a Control in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, system.reflection

I am new to  Visual Basic.NET ,I need to write down a piece of code to find the Top-Most Parent of a (User Control/Control) in Windows Form.

I have hundreds of controls on to Windows Form, some are User Controls and some built-in Windows controls

The code I have tested is adding multiple IF conditions but when controls are nested more then 2 levels  then its hard to add IF conditions.

Like:
**Form
--Panel
----Panel
------GroupBox
--------TextBox**

```
'Here is simple code
'A TextBox inside Panel control
Dim parent_control As Control = TryCast(txtbox, Control) 'casting that Control in generic Control
if parent_control.Parent Is Nothing Then
   Return 
Else
   Return parent_control.Parent.Parent
End If
```

I would be very thankful if somebody guide me in this regard.

Comment: When you say you've *been asked* ... I wonder if one should really hand you an answer.  So, a hint: try recursion?

Comment: Sir, Actually a function writing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is done through recursion:

```
#Region "Get Ultimate Parent"
Private Function GetParentForm(ByVal parent As Control) As Control
    Dim parent_control As Control = TryCast(parent, Control)
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Specific to a control means if you want to find only for certain control
    If TypeOf parent_control Is myControl Then   'myControl is of UserControl
        Return parent_control
    End If
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If parent_control.Parent Is Nothing Then
        Return parent_control
    End If
    If parent IsNot Nothing Then
        Return GetParentForm(parent.Parent)
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
#End Region
```

It worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

no need for recursion here.

```
Private Function UltimateParent(ByVal control as Control) As Control

  Do
    If Nothing Is control.Parent
      Return control
    Else
      control = control.Parent
    End If
  Loop

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

******You can use just  do

```
Dim Form As System.Windows.Forms.Form
Form = Combobox.FindForm()
```

'to find directy the parent form of  any controle without any For until******

Answer (score 1):

the ultimate would be the form, but you are really looking for a method to trace through, you could use either recursion or while loop:

```
Public Function FindTopMostParent(ctrl As Control) As Control
    If ctrl.Parent Is Nothing Then
        Return ctrl '// or nothing?
    End If

    Return FindTopMostParent(ctrl.Parent)
End Function

Public Function FindTopMostParent_v2(ctrl As Control) As Control
    Dim output As Control = ctrl

    While output.Parent IsNot Nothing
        output = output.Parent
    End While

    Return output
End Function
```

Comment: Rex: The thing is ultimate is obvious the Form but in case of UserControl there is no Form, so for user control it would be the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest

```
Public Function GetUltimateParent(ByVal ofThisControl As Control) As Control
    If ofThisControl Is Nothing return Nothing 'Error Check

    Dim ultimateParent As Control = ofThisControl
    While Not ultimateParent.Parent Is Nothing
        ultimateParent = ultimateParent.Parent
    End While

    Return ultimateParent
 End Function
```